# Как уменьшить font-size у tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как уменьшить font-size у tooltip?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Вы же знаете и как составляются css-селекторы, и как прописываются сами css-правила.

Comment: А какие способы вы уже попробовали, автор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по скрину достаточно этого:

```
.tooltips{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

PS: возможно чуть больше селектор нужно прописать, но направление вы поняли

Comment: Пробовал, но так не работает...